# Circular dependency between AWS Cloudformation stacks bad practice?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Just to clarify, I'm not pertaining about circular dependencies on the resource level.

I'm talking about 2 separate stacks, lets say Stack A and Stack B. Overtime they developed bi-directional dependencies to each other.
Stack A imports resources from Stack B and vice versa. And they work fine.

My worry is, the re-deployability aspect of the stack. Like if we decide to deploy it on another account,  they will fail to deploy since they need the other stack's resources to work.

Chicken and Egg problem basically.

Question is, should this situation be avoided? Or it's just a normal way of doing things?

Comment: Yes, this should be avoided for exactly the reason you already gave.

Comment: @luk2302 Would you say this also applies to references that will not cause failures? For example referencing IAM Roles from a different stack. In these situations, stack will deploy fine even if the roles does not exists.

Comment: @luk2302 Our current use case is a Pipeline stack referencing a Secret Manager instance from a different stack. And we want to add a restriction on the Secret so that only the Pipeline can access it. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: FYI, circular dependencies between stacks are not possible in CloudFormation if you're using explicit imports and exports.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself using any of the cdk "from" methods (fromAttributes, fromArn, ect) to import an existing resource into a stack, you need to take a long hard look at your stacks.

If they must be linked, then you should make all these stacks Nested Stacks under a common stack above them - and instead of using from, pass them as parameters into the stack creation: ie: (in python)

```
my_starting_stack = MyStartingStack(self, "StackID")
my_second_stack = SecondStack(self, "SecondID", special_bucket=my_starting_stack.special_bucket)
```

as long as both stacks are cdk.NestedStacks (python, but the nested stack class is available in all languages) and contained within the same stack then they will a) be deployed together always and b) not end up with any dependency locks by passing constructs between them

If they must be able to be deployed independently - and in theory, without the other one existing at all - then you should be adding some form of interaction layer between them - a REST Api or Websocket or something.

Ask yourself this question. If tomorrow you had to deploy one stack on one account and the other in an entirely different account, would they still be able to work? From your description the answer is no, and therefor they are too tightly coupled.

If an interaction layer (api) feels like overkill and they never need to be deployed independently, than make them NestedStacks in a single common main stack is the best practice for sharing resources between stacks.

Do note there are some situations where you dont have a choice.

If you are in an organization that has multiple aws accounts, one for each product (a common structure) you may have things that are automatically added to that account - such as VPC that is already hooked up to the other VPCs in other accounts when that account was created for your team. - These are situations where you have no choice. You cannot control that VPC, you cannot change it, and most certainly you don't want to create a new one every time you deploy a new stack. So importing this is a situation where the 'from' methods are valid usage.

Comment: We are in the exact situation you mentioned. We have several resources that are shared among different stacks. Things like secrets, vpcs, load balancers, etc. Also we deploy our pipelines and app stacks on different accounts. In those situations, do you have any red flags we should watch out in terms of dependencies/coupling?

Comment: if they are in different accounts they should be considered different services *and never cross account to each other* -- at least assuming your following Microservice patterns. That kind of tight coupling causes deployment delays.

If they are all the same service, then they should stay in the same account. If they are different services, they should get any shared info (ie secrets) from a centralized single deploy source (preferably behind an api or something similar)

Comment: but we're rapidly getting into design philosophy here which is subjective at best  - the above is my (rather harsh) view on how services/aws accounts/ect should be separated - but that doesn't always apply in all situations.

Comment: +1 for insight but I don't agree with "If you find yourself using any of the cdk "from" methods (fromAttributes, fromArn, ect) to import an existing resource into a stack, you need to take a long hard look at your stacks.". See https://theburningmonk.com/2022/05/how-to-work-around-cloudformation-circular-dependencies/

Comment: you may notice the end of my answer had examples of situations where you have no other choice. Perfect world would see all pieces of a single app in one stack, but alas - we live in the real world.